# Form variables failing to print when using echo $variablename

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a form that reads in the users name and email, then emails them a voucher via a PHP file, which looks like this:

```
<?php

  $deal = "offer or discount details";

  $to = "$email";
  $subject = "Tonights wheree voucher - $deal";
  $message = '
  <html>
    <body>
        Test email sent to <?php echo $email; ?>.
    </body>
  </html>
  ';

  $headers = "From: wheree <no-reply@wheree.co.uk>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

The form:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="details-form" method="get" action="test.php">
                 <fieldset>
                       <p>
                         <input id="name" name="name" title="Please enter your full name. " size="18" class="tagcheck" minlength="5" maxlength="60" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value=''};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue};" />
                       </p>
                       <p>
                         <input id="email" name="email" size="18" title="Please enter a valid email address. " class="required email" value="Email" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value=''};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue};" />
                       </p>
                       <p class="tickbox-wrapper">
                       <input id="accept-tick" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="required" title="You must accept our Terms & Conditions. " /> I accept the voucher usage <a href="/voucher-terms-and-conditions" alt="terms" class="terms-link">Terms & Conditions</a>.
                       </p>

                       <div id="RegisterErrors" style="display:none"></div>

                       <p>
                         <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Continue"/>
                       </p>
                 </fieldset>
</form>
```

This works fine, but doesn't echo the variable `$email` in the received email? I've also tried using `$_GET["email"]`, but again to no success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you duplicating variable $email to $to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to place an `echo` statement inside a single quoted string.  Concatenate it in:

```
  $message = '
  <html>
    <body>
        Test email sent to ' . $email . '.
    </body>
  </html>
  ';
```

Or better yet, switch to a double-quoted string for `$message`, in which `$email` can be interpolated.

```
  $message = "
  <html>
    <body>
        Test email sent to $email.
    </body>
  </html>
  ";
```

See the [PHP manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php) for more information on variable interpolation and the difference between single and double-quoting.

A third option if you have lots of variables and multiple lines is the [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which avoids quoting entirely.

```
  $message =<<<MESSAGE
  <html>
    <body>
        Test email sent to $email.
    </body>
  </html>
MESSAGE;
// Note that the MESSAGE; above MUST be at the start of its own line, with no indentation
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has solved my problem. One final question though, how can I print the value of an input of a form, in this case the email address, on the same page? I'm using the jQuery AjaxForm plug in to submit the form, so this should be possible. The end result should be something like 'Voucher sent to $email' - I've tried <?php echo $email ?> but it's not working. Thanks again.

Comment: If you mean to print the value on the page that submitted the Ajax request, that's more complicated. The PHP variable needs to be returned with the Ajax response and then updated on the page with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have `$echo` inside of single-quotes. Variables are not expanded in single-quotes in PHP. Try putting it in double-quotes.  Or, as also suggested, if you want to use single quotes, concatenate it in.

```
$foo = "HELLO";
echo 'Foo: $foo';       // Prints 'Foo: $foo'
echo 'Foo: ' . $foo;    // Prints 'Foo: HELLO'
echo "Foo: $foo";       // Prints 'Foo: HELLO'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

  $deal = "offer or discount details";
  $to = $_GET['email'];
  $subject = "Tonights wheree voucher - $deal";
  $message = '
  <html>
    <body>
        Test email sent to '.$to.'.
    </body>
  </html>
  ';

  $headers = "From: wheree <no-reply@wheree.co.uk>" . "\r\n" .
             "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```